# Can I install Edubuntu in windows using wubi?

Tags: 11.04, edubuntu

Edubuntu website offers two possible downloads, x86 and 64 bit. I need to be able to install Edubuntu on a computer with no internet access and allow it to run within Windows XP. I cannot do this as a dual boot installation due to policy limitations.

I can put the .iso on the computer, and I can put Wubi in the same folder. When I run Wubi, it does not give me the option to install from the downloaded Edubuntu 11.04 .iso (either version).

I can also open the Edubuntu .iso and view the various files.  the Wubi is not an included file in this .iso. Is there a downloadable version of Edubuntu that includes Wubi?  Or is there a way to force Wubi to install from the available downloaded version of Edubutu?  Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the standard Ubuntu Desktop edition with wubi, then install the edubuntu package(s) that you need.  This will allow you to use wubi and then also have edubuntu installed as well, without needing to download Edubuntu from them (note that Edubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. all have packages in Synaptic, and you can start from one of the other versions and become a different version)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try virtualbox? I am not very knowledgeable in the workings of this program, but i believe you can install a virtual OS inside xp by giving it the .iso file.

Another option, as Thomas mentioned, is to install edubuntu packages in Ubuntu.

**The following information is taken off of the edubuntu site**

***Installation on an existing Ubuntu system***

Edubuntu provides application bundles that group educational software by grade level. You can install from the Education category in the "Software Center" entry in the Applications menu or installing the following packages using your favorite package manager:

- ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool (

  ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary ( ages 6-12) educational application bundle

  ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary ( ages 13-18) educational application bundle

  ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary ( university level ) educational application bundle

You can also install all Edubuntu packages, including artwork by installing the edubuntu-desktop package.

More details on what's included in these bundles are available on the Ubuntu wiki.